# print a list of numbers, replace numbers with words multiples of 3,5 also 3and5 C

Tags: c, fizzbuzz

Had my midterm in "programming with C" last week, the final question was write a program to print a list of numbers from 1 - 100 but every multiple of 3 print fizz, multiple of 5 buzz, and multiple of 3 and 5 print fizzbuzz.  Just got my grade I got a 76% and I am sure I got every other question right, so I must have had errors in my code.  I am trying to figure it out (cannot remember what I wrote on paper) My problem is that I basically have it working, but it is also printing the number, and the number should be replaced by the word.   Here is the code I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
        int x,y;
        printf("this should count from 1 to 100, and instead of printing the multiples of 3 or 5 or 3 and 5 it should print words\n");
        for (x=1; x<=100; x++)
        {
                if (x%3==0)
                {
                    printf("fizz\n");
                }
                if (x%5==0)
                {
                    printf("buzz\n");
                }
                if (x%3==0 && x%5==0)
                {
                    printf("FizzBuzz\n");
                }
        printf("%d\n",x);
        }
return 0;
}
```

I do not actually get to "re-take" the test or anything like that so I am not trying to cheat, I am just baffled as to what I need to do here. the output I get is

```
1
2
fizz
3
4
buzz
5
fizz
6
7
8
fizz
9
buzz
10
11
fizz
12
13
14
fizz
buzz
FizzBuzz
15
16
```

Where it should look like this:

```
1
2
Fizz
4
Buzz
Fizz
7
8
Fizz
Buzz
11
Fizz
13
14
FizzBuzz
16
17
Fizz
```

Comment: that was happening because u have written printf() outside the condition so it will be executed every time irrespective of the condition.i modified your code please have a look.

Comment: i made a little change http://codepad.org/b3VvDdQ7

Answer (score 8):

**Your conditionals are wrong.** They should be:

```
if (x%3==0 && x%5==0)
{
    printf("FizzBuzz\n");
}
else if (x%3==0)
{
    printf("fizz\n");
}
else if (x%5==0)
{
    printf("buzz\n");
}
else
{
    printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

Remember, it's `FizzBuzz` **if both are divisible by 3 *and* 5**, and `Fizz` if the number is divisible by 3, and `Buzz` if the number is divisible by 5.

Comment: you should add "else printf("%d\n", x);

Comment: @DrorCohen: I didn't think it was necessary as I was addressing where his code went wrong, but I get your point. Edited. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (x=1; x<=100; x++)
    {
            if (x%3==0 && x%5==0)
            {
            printf("fizzbuzz\n");
            }
            else if (x%5==0)
            {
             printf("buzz\n");
             }
             else if (x%3==0)
             {
              printf("Fizz\n");
              }
              else {
              printf("%d\n",x);
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're very close, so I'll try to give you just a small hint. It seems like the directions only want you to do one `printf` per loop iteration. What keyword can you add to your `if` statements to make this happen? You're also going to want to put some kind of keyword before `printf("%d\n",x);` to keep it from executing everytime.

Also, please use the same indentation for each `if` block.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x;

for ( x = 1; x <= 100; x++ )
{
   if (x%3==0)
   {
      printf("fizz");
   }
   if (x%5==0)
   {
      printf("buzz");
   }
   if(x%3 && x%5)
   {
      printf("%d",x);
   }
   printf("\n");           
}
}
```

will give you what you are looking for.  Note the "fizzbuzz" output is built up using the first two if conditionals.

Comment: Palm to Forehead,  Why didn't I think of that... I knew that the reason the number was printing every time was because it was in my for loop, but I thought (erroneously) that I had to have some type of statement there.  I corrected the code, and it worked like a charm. One thing I do not understand though... Was if I do not do the "fizzbuzz" in my first "if statement" it didn't work. I had to do it in the first if, and that makes no sense to me, it seems like it wouldn't matter if it was in the following else ifs..   I didnt try it with just "ifs" again,  I tried it like jrd1 suggested.

Comment: Wow, I just tried mocj's solution, and it worked... seems to be more elegant.  Honestly It seems strange to me that it worked. it seems to me (a total novice) that last if statement would just print the number, I really do not get it, but that is genius.

Comment: @Non_Trad_Nick The inside of the for loop essentially reads like this:  Is it a multiple of 3? (x%3 == 0) then print "fizz" - now is it a multiple of 5 (x%5 == 0) then print "buzz".  Note at this point if it is a multiple of both 3 and 5 it will have printed "fizzbuzz".  The third if condition tests that it is not a multiple of 3 (x%3) - this is the same as (x%3!=0) AND (&&) not a multiple of 5 (x%5) (same as (x%5!=0).  So "if it is not a multiple of 3 and not a multiple of 5 then print the number"

Comment: @Non_Trad_Nick The "fizzbuzz" condition has to come first in jrd1's solution because the cascading if / else if construct only executes the body of the first matching conditional - in this problem you have overlapping conditionals so you have to specify the most narrow matching condition first (x%3==0 && x%5==0) before the wider matching ones (x%3==0), (x%5==0).  Take 15 for example - it matches all three sets of conditions so in jrd1's code a 15 will print whatever is in the first if conditionals body.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (x%3==0 && x%5==0)
            {
                 printf("FizzBuzz\n");
            }
            else if (x%3==0)
            {
            printf("fizz\n");
            }
            else if (x%5==0)
            {
                 printf("buzz\n");
            }
            else
                 printf("%d\n",x);
```

this will give proper output, as in your case  many conditions can come true in some cases dry run on the value of 15 , 5 and 3 on mine and your code both you will understand

Comment: i have less reputition for negative voting or commenting but @rishabh raj solution also have problems

Comment: i overlooked the order of the condition.the && part should be the first.

Comment: checkout http://codepad.org/b3VvDdQ7 .i am not getting what u are trying to say.u should be more specific and to the point.

Comment: i was saying about your previous comment, after edition it's more than perfect....:)

Comment: ya u r right in case of mockj code the special cases like 15,45,90 will not give the desired result as the if condition in the beginning will be executed and it will never reach the last if condition.i also did the same logical mistake but i later corrected it.thanks to u.:)

Comment: I am not helping others for reputition but i need it for making unlock different functionalities so can you upvote my answer as it is not wrong

Comment: zeeshan : i just did :) but the printf("%d",x) will also be in the condition loop.correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    int x,y;
    printf("this should count from 1 to 100, and instead of printing the multiples of 3 or 5 or 3 and 5 it should print words\n");
    for (x=1; x<=100; x++)
    {
          if (x%3==0 && x%5==0)
            {
                printf("FizzBuzz\n");
            }
           else  if (x%3==0)
            {
                printf("fizz\n");
            }
           else if (x%5==0)
            {
                printf("buzz\n");
            }
       else      
    printf("%d\n",x);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void ) {

// Initialize variable to count from 1 - 100.
  int counter;

/* Create a for loop to count from from 1 to no more than 100 and count by an iteration no more than #1. */
   for(counter = 1; counter <= 100; counter++)
   {

    if (!(counter % 3) && (!(counter % 5)))
            {
               printf("fizzBuzz\n");
            }

           else  if (!(counter % 7 ))
            {
               printf("Fizz\n");
            }
            else  if (!(counter % 5 ))
            {
               printf("Buzz\n");
            }

            /* By placing "printf("%d\n", counter);" in curly brackets "{ }" within the else statement you are able to override the numbers in the previous statements with the desired text you wish to input.*/
            else
            {
               printf("%d\n", counter);
            }
   }

return (0);
}
```

/* p.s. for the love of god please do not use variables like 'i' or 'j'. It is bad programming as it make your code harder to read and understand. */

Answer (score -1):

How can I print a list of numbers, replace numbers with words multiples of 3,5 also 3 and 5 C ?

```c
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

    if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
      System.out.println("fizzbuzz" + ", ");
    } else if (i % 3 == 0) {
      System.out.println("fizz" + ",");
    } else if (i % 5 == 0) {
      System.out.println("buzz" + ", ");
    } else {
      System.out.println(i + ",");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your answer has a few flaws: 1) code-only answers are discouraged. You should address where the OP was wrong and how to fix it. 2) The language tags added to questions have a meaning. This question is tagged as C and only as C question. Your answer is clearly not valid C code but probably C# which makes it not answering the question. 3) Given the large number of existing answers to this years old question you might think again if yet another answer is adding some new information.